# Background color row

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have created a display method on a datasource of a form to check for a match on a certain field, if there are 2 of the same values, the specific row in the form should get a background color.

The problem with below code is that all lines in the form are given the background color, also if only 1 line record matches.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
    {
        SalesLine  salesLineLocal;
        ;

        salesLineLocal = _record;

         while select salesLineLocal
            where salesLineLocal.SerialId == salesLine.SerialId

        if(salesLineLocal.RecId != SalesLine.RecId)
        {
                _options.backColor(Winapi::RGB2int(251,181,251));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your method as following, this will work fine:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
    SalesLine  salesLineCurrent;
    SalesLine  salesLineLocal;
    ;

    salesLineCurrent = _record;

    select firstOnly RecId from salesLineLocal
        where salesLineLocal.SerialId == salesLineCurrent.SerialId
           && salesLineLocal.RecId    != salesLineCurrent.RecId;

    if (salesLineLocal.RecId)
    {
        _options.backColor(Winapi::RGB2int(251,181,251));
    }

    super(_record, _options);
}
```

but if you would like improve it you can move validation logic on the table level. On `SalesLine` table create method

```
public boolean hasDupplicate()
{
    SalesLine  salesLine;
    ;

    select firstOnly RecId from salesLine
        where salesLine.SerialId == this.SerialId
           && salesLine.RecId    != this.RecId;

    return salesLine.RecId != 0
}
```

Then your `displayOption` method will look like

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
    SalesLine  salesLineLocal;
    ;

    salesLineLocal = _record;

    if (salesLineLocal.hasDupplicate())
    {
        _options.backColor(Winapi::RGB2int(251,181,251));
    }

    super(_record, _options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer Aliaksandr! It works perfect! I only have changed the select firstOnly RecId, to select firstOnly SerialId, so it doesn't select blank serial id rows. Thanks again.